# Listando datas com primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, data

Estou listando datas usando o `convertDateTime`, o problema é deste jeito ele sempre apresenta o dia anterior ao que está sendo lido base de dados. Sem o `convertDateTime` ele apresentada a data correcta.

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.dataperf}">
     <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" tipe="date"/>                           
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: Não será um problema do fuso horário? [Veja esta resposta no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12351693/1473534)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351244/jsf-convertdatetime-renders-the-previous-day

Da uma lida nesse topico aqui man. Acredito que será util pra ti.

Comment: Boas LazyFox e Rodrigo Nantes. Obrigado pelas vossas ajudas, encontrei no link sugerido a solução.